# How do I add navigation drawer to my existing code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-navigation

I have an app in which I have a navigation panel with menu buttons on which I want to apply navigation drawer, currently it takes up the entire screen,but I want to restrict it to 3/4th of the screen by applying navigation drawer on it, but i have never touched navigation drawer before so have no clue, any help or guidance will be great.Also went through some documentation and got confused :(
Here is my code:

and here is my layout class for navigation panel:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.justin.a"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_texture"
    android:clickable="true" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/nav_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/nav_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/nav_margin"
    android:background="#242424"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/nav_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/nav_padding"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:showDividers="middle"

             >


             <com.justin.a.utils.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_option_dashboard"
                style="@style/a.TextView.NavigationItem"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_ht"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
                android:onClick="onDashboardClicked"
                android:text="@string/nav_option_dashboard"
                android:textSize="@dimen/navigation_panel_text"
                foo:customFont="cabin.medium.ttf"
                android:padding="@dimen/nav_option_padding"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_background_button"
                    />  
            <com.justin.a.utils.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_option_news"
                style="@style/a.TextView.NavigationItem"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_ht"
                foo:customFont="cabin.medium.ttf"
                android:textSize="@dimen/navigation_panel_text"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
                android:onClick="onNewsClicked"
                android:text="@string/nav_option_news"
                android:padding="@dimen/nav_option_padding"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_background_button"

                 />

            <com.justin.a.utils.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_option_markets"
                style="@style/a.TextView.NavigationItem"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_ht"
                android:textSize="@dimen/navigation_panel_text"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
                android:onClick="onMarketClicked"
                android:text="@string/nav_option_markets" 
                foo:customFont="cabin.medium.ttf"
                android:padding="@dimen/nav_option_padding"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_background_button"

                />

            <com.justin.a.utils.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_option_lists"
                style="@style/a.TextView.NavigationItem"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_ht"
                android:textSize="@dimen/navigation_panel_text"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
                android:text="@string/nav_option_lists"
                foo:customFont="cabin.medium.ttf"
                android:onClick="onListsClicked"
                android:padding="@dimen/nav_option_padding"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_background_button"

               />

            <!--  UncommentForAlerts- Remove android:visibility="gone" -->
            <com.justin.a.utils.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_option_alerts"
                style="@style/a.TextView.NavigationItem"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_ht"
                android:textSize="@dimen/navigation_panel_text"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
                foo:customFont="cabin.medium.ttf"
                android:padding="@dimen/nav_option_padding"
                android:onClick="onAlertsClicked"
                android:text="@string/nav_option_alerts" 
                android:background="@drawable/nav_background_button"
                android:visibility="gone"

                />

            <com.justin.a.utils.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_option_briefcase"
                style="@style/a.TextView.NavigationItem"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_ht"
                android:textSize="@dimen/navigation_panel_text"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
                foo:customFont="cabin.medium.ttf"
                android:padding="@dimen/nav_option_padding"
                android:onClick="onBriefcaseClicked"
                android:text="@string/nav_option_briefcase" 
                android:background="@drawable/nav_background_button"


                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_information"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/nav_padding"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_settings"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/nav_padding"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_information" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_logout"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/nav_padding"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_information"
          />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also here is my `navigationpanelfragment.java`:
--UPDATE----

```
public class NavigationPanelFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    public static final String TAG_NAVIGATION_PANEL_FRAGMENT = "NavigationPanelFragment";
    public static final String ACTIVE_MENU_ITEM = "ActiveMenuItem";
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private Fragment lvDrawer;
    public static void newInstance(final FragmentManager manager, final String activeFragmentTag) {
        final NavigationPanelFragment fragment = new NavigationPanelFragment();
        final Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(NavigationPanelFragment.ACTIVE_MENU_ITEM, activeFragmentTag);
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);

        final FragmentInfo fragmentInfo = new FragmentInfo(TransactionMethods.ADD);
        fragmentInfo.setAnimation(R.anim.slide_in_from_left, FragmentInfo.NO_ANIMATION);
        fragmentInfo.setPopAnimation(0, R.anim.slide_out_to_left);
        fragmentInfo.setFragmentTag(TAG_NAVIGATION_PANEL_FRAGMENT);
        fragmentInfo.doNotAddToBackStack();
        fragmentInfo.setActionBarTitle(Application.getAppResources().getString(R.string.title_applications));
        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().transitionFragment(manager, fragment, fragmentInfo);
    }

    public static void removeInstance(final FragmentManager manager) {

        Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_NAVIGATION_PANEL_FRAGMENT);
        if (fragment == null) {
            return;
        }

        manager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(0, R.anim.slide_out_to_left).remove(fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    private LogoutListener mLogoutListener = new LogoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLogoutOperationFired() {
            final Activity activity = getActivity();
            if(activity != null){
                LoginActivity.newInstance(activity);
                UserProfileManager.clearUserProfileManager();
                FragmentStackManager.getInstance().clearBackStack(getFragmentManager());
                activity.finish();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_panel, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        final ImageButton logoutButton = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.button_logout);
        logoutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        logoutButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_signout_nav_panel));

        final ImageButton infoButton = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.button_information);
        infoButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        infoButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_info_nav_panel));

        final ImageButton settingsButton = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.button_settings);
        settingsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        settingsButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_prefs_nav_panel));

        highlightActiveMenuItem();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mLogoutListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        MenuUtils.disableSearchMenu(getActivity());
        MenuUtils.disableAlertMenu(getActivity());
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        MenuUtils.enableSearchMenu(getActivity());
        MenuUtils.enableAlertMenu(getActivity());
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_logout:

                final DialogFragment dialog = new LogoutCancelSignoutDialogFragment(mLogoutListener);
                dialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), AbsBaseaActivity.TAG_LOGOUT_DIALOG);
\               break;
            case R.id.button_information:
                leaveMainActivity();
                InformationActivity.newInstance(getActivity());
\               break;
            case R.id.button_settings:
                leaveMainActivity();
                PreferencesActivity.newInstance(getActivity());
\               break;
        }
    }
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle getDrawerToggle() {
        return drawerToggle;
    }

    private void leaveMainActivity() {
        removeInstance(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        final MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setNavigationOpen(false);
    }

    private void highlightActiveMenuItem() {
        TextView highlightedTextView = null;
        final String activeFragmentTitle = "";//getArguments().getString(ACTIVE_MENU_ITEM);
        final Resources resources = Application.getAppResources();

        if (resources.getString(R.string.nav_option_news).equals(activeFragmentTitle)) {
            highlightedTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nav_option_news);

        } else if (resources.getString(R.string.nav_option_markets).equals(activeFragmentTitle)) {
            highlightedTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nav_option_markets);

        } else if (resources.getString(R.string.nav_option_lists).equals(activeFragmentTitle)) {
            highlightedTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nav_option_lists);
        } else if (resources.getString(R.string.nav_option_alerts).equals(activeFragmentTitle)) {
            highlightedTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nav_option_alerts);
        }
        else if (resources.getString(R.string.nav_option_briefcase).equals(activeFragmentTitle)) {
            highlightedTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nav_option_briefcase);
        } else {
            highlightedTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nav_option_dashboard);
        }

        highlightedTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_orange));

    }

}
```

Here is my acitvity_main.xml (it works, shows a blank panel on swipe)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


  <!-- <include layout="@layout/main_title"/> -->

  <!-- <Button android:text="Main" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn_refreshbtn_refresh" android:layout_width="wrap_content">

  </Button> -->
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/altercolor2">
    </FrameLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="#666"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#333"
        android:paddingLeft="15sp"
        android:paddingRight="15sp"
        android:name="com.justin.jar.fragments.NavigationPanelFragment"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

----UPDATED----

Also here is my `mainactivity.java` (it has the navigation panel reference which i need to add under navigation drawer):

```
public class MainActivity extends AbsBaseaActivity implements OnBackStackChangedListener {
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_LIST = 100;
    private boolean mIsNavigationOpen = false;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationPanelFragment dlDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private boolean mIsSearchBarActive;
     private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
        private CharSequence mTitle;
    public boolean isNavigationOpen() {
        return mIsNavigationOpen;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setNavigationOpen(final boolean isNavigationOpen) {
        this.mIsNavigationOpen = isNavigationOpen;
        final ImageButton mainButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_main);
        if(isNavigationOpen) {
            mainButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_helios_active);
        } else {
            mainButton.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        }
    }


    public static void newInstance(final Activity activity) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
// 2. App Icon 
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        // 2.1 create ActionBarDrawerToggle

                 actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
                            R.drawable.arrow_up, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);


                // 2.2 Set actionBarDrawerToggle as the DrawerListener
                drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        initiateMainActionBar();

        final FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mActiveFragment = DashboardFragment.getInstanceWithTransition(supportFragmentManager);

        } else {
            //resetToDashboard(supportFragmentManager);
        }
        //setup drawer

        /* Set up the drawer toggle */
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.arrow_up, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("");
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (dlDrawer.getDrawerToggle().onOptionsItemSelected((android.view.MenuItem) item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
         actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    private void setupOnClickListenerForMainButton() {
        final ImageButton mainButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_main);
        mainButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                toggleNavigationPanel();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void manageActionBar() {
        setTitle(null);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(final int featureId, final MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                toggleNavigationPanel();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BroadcastActions.USER_PROFILE);
        filter.addAction(BroadcastActions.NEWS_IMAGE);
        filter.addAction(BroadcastActions.NEWS_HEADLINES);

        registerReceiver(mMainActivityReceiver, filter);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(mMainActivityReceiver);
        super.onPause();
        BangoAgent.onIdle();
    }

    public void pushNewsArticlePagerFragment(final int position, final String selectedCategoryCode, final boolean isMyNews) {
        NewsArticlePagerFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager(), position, selectedCategoryCode, isMyNews);
    }

    public void onDashboardClicked(final View view) {
        toggleNavigationPanel();

        if (isFragmentVisible(DashboardFragment.TAG_DASHBOARD_FRAGMENT)) {
            return;
        }

        final FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_right, R.anim.slide_out_to_left);
        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().clearBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mActiveFragment = DashboardFragment.getInstance();
        transaction.hide(mActiveFragment);
        transaction.show(mActiveFragment);
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        updateActionBarTitle();
    }

    public void onNewsClicked(final View view) {
        if(mIsNavigationOpen) {
            toggleNavigationPanel();
        }

        if (isFragmentVisible(NewsFragment.TAG_NEWS_FRAGMENT)) {
            return;
        }

        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().clearBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mActiveFragment = NewsFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager());
        updateActionBarTitle();
    }

    public void onMarketClicked(final View view) {
        if(mIsNavigationOpen) {
            toggleNavigationPanel();
        }

        if (isFragmentVisible(MarketsFragment.TAG_MARKETS_FRAGMENT)) {
            return;
        }

        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().clearBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mActiveFragment = MarketsFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager());
        updateActionBarTitle();
    }

    public void onListsClicked(final View view) {
        if(mIsNavigationOpen) {
            toggleNavigationPanel();
        }

        if (isFragmentVisible(ListsContainerFragment.TAG_LIST_CONTAINER_FRAGMENT)) {
            return;
        }

        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().clearBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mActiveFragment = ListsContainerFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager());
        updateActionBarTitle();
    }

    public void onBriefcaseClicked(final View view) {
        if(mIsNavigationOpen) {
            toggleNavigationPanel();
        }

        if (isFragmentVisible(BriefcaseFragment.TAG_BRIEFCASE_FRAGMENT)) {
            return;
        }

        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().clearBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mActiveFragment = BriefcaseFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager());
        updateActionBarTitle();
    }

    public void onAlertsClicked(final View view) {
        if(mIsNavigationOpen) {
            toggleNavigationPanel();
        }

        if (isFragmentVisible(AlertsContainerFragment.TAG_ALERTS_CONTAINER_FRAGMENT)){
            return;
        }

        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().clearBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mActiveFragment = AlertsContainerFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager());
        updateActionBarTitle();

    }

    private void toggleNavigationPanel() {
        final FragmentStackManager manager = FragmentStackManager.getInstance();
        if (mIsNavigationOpen) {
            NavigationPanelFragment.removeInstance(getSupportFragmentManager());
            updateActionBarTitle();
            BangoHelper.eventMainNav();
        } else {
            final TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_title);
            title.setText(getString(R.string.title_applications));
            NavigationPanelFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager(), manager.getTopTitle());
        }


        setNavigationOpen(!mIsNavigationOpen);
    }

    public void updateActionBarTitle() {
        final String title = FragmentStackManager.getInstance().getTopTitle();
        final TextView titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_title);
        titleView.setText(title);
    }

    private boolean isFragmentVisible(final String tag) {
        Fragment fragment = FragmentStackManager.getInstance().getTopFragment();
        return fragment != null && tag.equals(fragment.getTag());
    }

    public interface BackPressListener<T extends Fragment> {
        public boolean backPressed(MainActivity fragmentActivity);
    }

    private BackPressListener<Fragment> backPressListener = null;
    public void setBackPressListener (final BackPressListener<Fragment> backPressListener) {
            this.backPressListener = backPressListener;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (backPressListener != null) {
            boolean b = false;
            // Making sure we trigger the backPressed event if the listener is the top fragment
            String bplTag = ((Fragment)backPressListener).getTag();
            Fragment topFragment = FragmentStackManager.getInstance().getTopFragment();
            String topFragemtnTag = "";
            if (topFragment != null) {
                topFragemtnTag = topFragment.getTag();
    }

        if (mIsSearchBarActive) {
            MenuUtils.hideSearchView(this);
            mIsSearchBarActive = false;
        } else if (mIsNavigationOpen) {
            toggleNavigationPanel();
        } else if (!FragmentStackManager.getInstance().popTopFragment()) {
            Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(setIntent);
        } else {
            Fragment topFragment = FragmentStackManager.getInstance().getTopFragment();
            if (topFragment == null) {
                mActiveFragment = DashboardFragment.getInstance();
                ((DashboardFragment)mActiveFragment).refreshDashboard();
            } else if (topFragment instanceof AbsArticlePagerFragment) {
                ((AbsArticlePagerFragment) topFragment).forceUpdateTextSize();
            } else if (topFragment instanceof AbsBaseArticleFragment) {
                ((AbsBaseArticleFragment) topFragment).forceUpdateTextSize();
            }
        }

        updateActionBarTitle();
    }


    public void setActiveFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
        mActiveFragment = fragment;
    }

    public void setIsSearchBarActive(final boolean isSearchBarActive){
        mIsSearchBarActive = isSearchBarActive;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        for (int i = 0; i < getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount(); i++) {
            final BackStackEntry bse = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(i);
            Log.d("BackStack", "Changed: " + bse.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_LIST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Fragment fragment = FragmentStackManager.getInstance().getTopFragment();

                if (fragment == null) { // Implies DashboardFragment because dashboard was never added to backstack
                    DashboardFragment.getInstance().onUpdate();
                } else if (fragment instanceof ListsContainerFragment) {
                    ((ListsContainerFragment) fragment).onUpdate();
                } else if (fragment instanceof ListDetailsFragment) {
                    ((ListDetailsFragment) fragment).onUpdate(data);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void refreshScreen() {
        Fragment fragment = FragmentStackManager.getInstance().getTopFragment();

        if (fragment == null) { // Implies DashboardFragment
            DashboardFragment.getInstance().refreshScreen();
        } else if (fragment instanceof ListsContainerFragment) {
            ((ListsContainerFragment) fragment).refreshScreen();
        } else if (fragment instanceof ListDetailsFragment) {
            ((ListDetailsFragment) fragment).refreshScreen();
        } else if (fragment instanceof MarketsFragment) {
            ((MarketsFragment) fragment).refreshScreen();
        }else if (fragment instanceof AlertsContainerFragment) {
            ((AlertsContainerFragment) fragment).refreshScreen();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        dlDrawer.getDrawerToggle().onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also add activity_main.xml ,I think that needs to be altered for the navigation panel to show up for nav drawer

Comment: you are right,I will edit my code to reflect mainactivity and activity_main

Comment: This is a kind request, instead of an answer, and as such I will not post this as an answer. Please let the Action Bar stay in place when the drawer is opened! Not doing so conflicts with the designer guidelines and annoys me to no end. Thank you!

Comment: the action bar stays in place. only the main activity is altered to support the nav layout fragment on swipe , which is the whole point behind nav drawer. do you have any clue how this works?

Answer (score 2):

This is a good article to follow for adding a navigation drawer: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Your navigation drawer is showing a blank panel, because the drawer view in your activity_main.xml is a ListView (which you haven't set any data to).

You want to make this view your fragment.

Your activity_main.xml file should look like. Make sure to replace the class on the fragment tag to the correct class of your navigation fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!-- This fragment container is your the place to put your activities content -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/altercolor2" />

    <!--
    This is your navigation drawer. You can adjust the width here, but it should
    be between 240dp and 320dp
    -->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        class="com.yourapp.NavigationPanelFragment" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Your MainActivity should look something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AbsBaseaActivity implements OnBackStackChangedListener {
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_LIST = 100;

    private Fragment mDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    public boolean isNavigationOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawer);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setNavigationOpen(final boolean isNavigationOpen) {
        final ImageButton mainButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_main);
        if(isNavigationOpen) {
            mainButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_helios_active);
        } else {
            mainButton.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        }
    }




    public static void newInstance(final Activity activity) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        initiateMainActionBar();

        final FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mActiveFragment = DashboardFragment.getInstanceWithTransition(supportFragmentManager);
            BangoHelper.onStartSession(this);

        } else {
            resetToDashboard(supportFragmentManager);
        }

        //setup drawer


        //this is our drawer layout that contains the navigation drawer and your content
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        //this is the navigation drawer fragment
        mDrawer = (NavigationPanelFragment) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    }

    private void resetToDashboard(final FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().clearBackStack(supportFragmentManager);
        mActiveFragment = DashboardFragment.getInstanceWithNoTransition(supportFragmentManager);
    }

    private void initiateMainActionBar() {
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_main);
        setupOnClickListenerForSearchButton(this);
        setupOnClickListenerForMainButton();
        setupOnClickListenerForSearchCancelButton(this);
        setupOnClickListenerForSearchClearButton(this);
    }

    private void setupOnClickListenerForSearchCancelButton(final MainActivity activity) {
        final Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_search_cancel);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                final View actionBarView = findViewById(R.id.action_bar_container);
                mIsSearchBarActive = MenuUtils.changeActionBar(activity, actionBarView);
            }
        });
    }


    private void setupOnClickListenerForMainButton() {
        final ImageButton mainButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_main);
        mainButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                toggleNavigationPanel();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void manageActionBar() {
        setTitle(null);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(final int featureId, final MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                toggleNavigationPanel();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BroadcastActions.USER_PROFILE);
        filter.addAction(BroadcastActions.NEWS_IMAGE);
        filter.addAction(BroadcastActions.NEWS_HEADLINES);

        registerReceiver(mMainActivityReceiver, filter);
        BangoAgent.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(mMainActivityReceiver);
        super.onPause();
        saveTextSize();
    }

    private void saveTextSize() {
        final ContentResolver resolver = EikonApplication.getAppContext().getContentResolver();
        final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(GenericColumns.TEXT_SIZE, SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getTextSize().ordinal());

        SqlArguments argument = SqlArgumentsFactory.generateUserProfileUpdateSqlArguments();
        String where = argument.getWhereClause();
        String[] whereArgs = argument.getWhereArgs();
        resolver.update(UserProfileContentProvider.USER_PROFILE_URI, contentValues, where, whereArgs);
    }

    public void pushNewsArticlePagerFragment(final int position, final String selectedCategoryCode, final boolean isMyNews) {
        NewsArticlePagerFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager(), position, selectedCategoryCode, isMyNews);
    }

    public void onDashboardClicked(final View view) {
        toggleNavigationPanel();

        if (isFragmentVisible(DashboardFragment.TAG_DASHBOARD_FRAGMENT)) {
            return;
        }

        final FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_right, R.anim.slide_out_to_left);
        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().clearBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mActiveFragment = DashboardFragment.getInstance();
        transaction.hide(mActiveFragment);
        transaction.show(mActiveFragment);
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        updateActionBarTitle();
    }

    public void onNewsClicked(final View view) {
        if(mIsNavigationOpen) {
            toggleNavigationPanel();
        }

        if (isFragmentVisible(NewsFragment.TAG_NEWS_FRAGMENT)) {
            return;
        }

        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().clearBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mActiveFragment = NewsFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager());
        updateActionBarTitle();
    }

    public void onMarketClicked(final View view) {
        if(mIsNavigationOpen) {
            toggleNavigationPanel();
        }

        if (isFragmentVisible(MarketsFragment.TAG_MARKETS_FRAGMENT)) {
            return;
        }

        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().clearBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mActiveFragment = MarketsFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager());
        updateActionBarTitle();
    }

    public void onListsClicked(final View view) {
        if(mIsNavigationOpen) {
            toggleNavigationPanel();
        }

        if (isFragmentVisible(ListsContainerFragment.TAG_LIST_CONTAINER_FRAGMENT)) {
            return;
        }

        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().clearBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mActiveFragment = ListsContainerFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager());
        updateActionBarTitle();
    }

    public void onBriefcaseClicked(final View view) {
        if(mIsNavigationOpen) {
            toggleNavigationPanel();
        }

        if (isFragmentVisible(BriefcaseFragment.TAG_BRIEFCASE_FRAGMENT)) {
            return;
        }

        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().clearBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mActiveFragment = BriefcaseFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager());
        updateActionBarTitle();
    }

    public void onAlertsClicked(final View view) {
        if(mIsNavigationOpen) {
            toggleNavigationPanel();
        }

        if (isFragmentVisible(AlertsContainerFragment.TAG_ALERTS_CONTAINER_FRAGMENT)){
            return;
        }

        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().clearBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mActiveFragment = AlertsContainerFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager());
        updateActionBarTitle();

    }

    private void toggleNavigationPanel() {

    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawer))
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawer);
        else mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawer);
        final FragmentStackManager manager = FragmentStackManager.getInstance();

        setNavigationOpen(setNavigationOpen());
    }

    public void updateActionBarTitle() {
        final String title = FragmentStackManager.getInstance().getTopTitle();
        final TextView titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_title);
        titleView.setText(title);
    }

    private boolean isFragmentVisible(final String tag) {
        Fragment fragment = FragmentStackManager.getInstance().getTopFragment();
        return fragment != null && tag.equals(fragment.getTag());
    }

    public interface BackPressListener<T extends Fragment> {
        public boolean backPressed(MainActivity fragmentActivity);
    }

    private BackPressListener<Fragment> backPressListener = null;
    public void setBackPressListener (final BackPressListener<Fragment> backPressListener) {
            this.backPressListener = backPressListener;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        BangoHelper.eventBack();
        if (backPressListener != null) {
            boolean b = false;
            // Making sure we trigger the backPressed event if the listener is the top fragment
            String bplTag = ((Fragment)backPressListener).getTag();
            Fragment topFragment = FragmentStackManager.getInstance().getTopFragment();
            String topFragemtnTag = "";
            if (topFragment != null) {
                topFragemtnTag = topFragment.getTag();
                if (bplTag != null && topFragemtnTag != null && bplTag.equals(topFragemtnTag)) {
                    b = backPressListener.backPressed(this);
                }
            }
            if (b) {
                return;
            }

        }

        if (mIsSearchBarActive) {
            MenuUtils.hideSearchView(this);
            mIsSearchBarActive = false;
        } else if (mIsNavigationOpen) {
            toggleNavigationPanel();
        } else if (!FragmentStackManager.getInstance().popTopFragment()) {
            Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(setIntent);
        } else {
            Fragment topFragment = FragmentStackManager.getInstance().getTopFragment();
            if (topFragment == null) {
                mActiveFragment = DashboardFragment.getInstance();
                ((DashboardFragment)mActiveFragment).refreshDashboard();
            } else if (topFragment instanceof AbsArticlePagerFragment) {
                ((AbsArticlePagerFragment) topFragment).forceUpdateTextSize();
            } else if (topFragment instanceof AbsBaseArticleFragment) {
                ((AbsBaseArticleFragment) topFragment).forceUpdateTextSize();
            }
        }

        updateActionBarTitle();
    }


    public void setActiveFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
        mActiveFragment = fragment;
    }

    public void setIsSearchBarActive(final boolean isSearchBarActive){
        mIsSearchBarActive = isSearchBarActive;
    }


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_LIST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Fragment fragment = FragmentStackManager.getInstance().getTopFragment();

                if (fragment == null) { // Implies DashboardFragment because dashboard was never added to backstack
                    DashboardFragment.getInstance().onUpdate();
                } else if (fragment instanceof ListsContainerFragment) {
                    ((ListsContainerFragment) fragment).onUpdate();
                } else if (fragment instanceof ListDetailsFragment) {
                    ((ListDetailsFragment) fragment).onUpdate(data);
                }else if (fragment instanceof AlertsContainerFragment) {
                    ((AlertsContainerFragment) fragment).onUpdate();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void refreshScreen() {
        Fragment fragment = FragmentStackManager.getInstance().getTopFragment();

        if (fragment == null) { // Implies DashboardFragment
            DashboardFragment.getInstance().refreshScreen();
        } else if (fragment instanceof ListsContainerFragment) {
            ((ListsContainerFragment) fragment).refreshScreen();
        } else if (fragment instanceof ListDetailsFragment) {
            ((ListDetailsFragment) fragment).refreshScreen();
        } else if (fragment instanceof MarketsFragment) {
            ((MarketsFragment) fragment).refreshScreen();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void retryLoginDelayedData(){
        LoginFragment f = new LoginFragment();
        f.login("delayed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        FragmentStackManager stackManager = FragmentStackManager.getInstance();
        Fragment topFragment = stackManager.getTopFragment();
        if(topFragment != null){
            if(topFragment instanceof ChartFragment){
                ChartFragment.replaceInstance(((ChartFragment)topFragment), getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.fragment_container);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the state of the navigation drawer is managed by the drawer layout. The DrawerLayout and the drawer fragment is bound up in the onCreate method.

Refer to the article i mentioned if you run into trouble.

--- EDIT ----

Below is an activity I have used in an app. It shows how to add the drawer toggle (the link I posted also shows this).

You should be able to merge this with your current activity and have a working navigation drawer.

```
public class SampleActivity extends AbsBaseaActivity {

    private Fragment mDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerMenuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.home_menu_drawer_titles);
        mDrawer = (fragment) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        /* Set up the drawer toggle */
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_closed) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.activity_title);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    }

    /**
     * Backward-compatible version of {@link ActionBar#getThemedContext()} that
     * simply returns the {@link android.app.Activity} if <code>getThemedContext</code> is unavailable.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) private Context getActionBarThemedContextCompat() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            return getActionBar().getThemedContext();
        } else {
            return this;
        }
    }

    @Override protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        mDrawer.setItemChecked(0, true);
    }

    @Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawer)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawer);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawer);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

If you are having errors, then post what the errors are.

Comment: The exception is a problem in your layout file. Can you post the activity layout file that crashes? The activity layout should have a fragment tag instead of a listview tag.

Comment: Create an interface in your navigation fragment that has a closeDrawer() method. Have your activity implement that interface, and in your on create create the interface member variable, and set it to the fragment. Then when an item is clicked in your navigation fragment, call the interfaces' closeDrawer method, which the activity will handle.

Comment: can you show me programmatically? I understand the concept but didn't have a luck implementing it.Always run into errors.Will update my code to point to the latest code with working fragment I have (but it doesn't close on button click within the nav fragment contained in the drawerlayout

Comment: I have updated my code with the latest working fragment code, can you explain your idea with respect to my navigationpanelfragment and mainactivity for the closing of the drawer on click of the items contained within the navigation fragment panel

Answer (score 0):

U can get source ode for navigation drawer from the link below

http://hmkcode.com/android-creating-a-navigation-drawer/

copy this to workspace, or open as a new android project from existing source code.

right click on project > properties >java buildpath> add external jar> choose latest V13 support library from android sdks installed and in order and export tick the jar v13

again right click on project > properties >android>choose abs library. [google for library]

U will get error free working project

Comment: my code is based on fragments, how do I customize my existing code to include that?

Comment: Down voting for not using English, which is default on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

All the answer above are awesome but I found it little bit difficult to add it in my existing code so I have created a new class which uses animation and LayoutInflater to add view and removes the navigation drawer to the activity you can use it in fragment also.

*NavigationDrawer.java*

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;

import static android.content.Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;

public class NavigationDrawer {

//State is the visible state
private Boolean state = false, Transition = false;
private ConstraintLayout mainView;
private ConstraintLayout navigationLayout;
private Animation show, hide;

public NavigationDrawer(Activity activity, ConstraintLayout view) {

    this.mainView = view;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
activity.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    navigationLayout = (ConstraintLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer, 
mainView, false);

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    //Show animation
    show = new TranslateAnimation(-displayMetrics.widthPixels, 0, 0, 0);
    show.setDuration(500);
    show.getFillAfter();
    show.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            Transition = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Transition = false;
            state = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    //Hide animation
    hide = new TranslateAnimation(0, -displayMetrics.widthPixels, 0, 0);
    hide.setDuration(500);
    hide.getFillAfter();

    hide.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            Transition = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Transition = false;
            state = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
}

public void toggle() {
    if (!Transition) {
        if (!state) {
            mainView.addView(navigationLayout);
            navigationLayout.startAnimation(show);
        } else {
            navigationLayout.startAnimation(hide);
            mainView.removeView(navigationLayout);
        }
    }
}
}
```

To use this class.

```
NavigationDrawer navigationDrawer = new 
NavigationDrawer(this,user_activity_main_layout);

//To toggle it
navigationDrawer.toggle();
```

Here *user_activity_main_layout* is the Id of root ConstrainLayout you can choose whatever you want.
This works perfect.