# Add navigation drawer to content view containing ListView and Button

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I have a view layout containing a `ListView` and a `Button`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:background="#5434"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:id="@+id/itemlistView" tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam"/>


 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam">

       <Button
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/button"
              android:text="@string/new_item"
              android:id="@+id/listview_addDebtButton"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:layout_weight="1.0"
              tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

but now i want to add a `Navigation Drawer`. Using the sample code from [google developers](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). But am not sure how to do this since the sample code contains an empty content view:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. A solid background is used for contrast
     with the content view. -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

I however proceeded to try with this as my new layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/itemlistView" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="@string/new_item"
            android:id="@+id/listview_addDebtButton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. A solid background is used for contrast
     with the content view. -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

This fails woefully when I try to run the app and i get a `android.view.InflateException` with the error message:

`error inflating class DrawerLayout`. Am not sure how to proceed from here. "There is a similar question that asks ["How do I add navigation drawer to my existing code?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980945/how-do-i-add-navigation-drawer-to-my-existing-code/20103723#20103723) but this problem is way too complicated than mine and I can't apply the solutions to my problem. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

**According to docs:** Drawer Layout tooks two direct children

> Inside the DrawerLayout, add one view that contains the main content
>   for the screen (your primary layout when the drawer is hidden) and
>   another view that contains the contents of the navigation drawer.

From that reference I used one for FrameLayout and another one for ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/itemlistView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/listview_addDebtButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="@string/new_item"
                tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```