# How to add navigation drawer in MainActivity Tab Layout?

Tags: android

Please teach me how to add navigation drawer in this activity.

**MainActivity** (Tab Layout)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        assert tabLayout != null;
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.welcome));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.venue));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return new WelcomeFragment();
                    case 1:
                        return new pptp();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 2;
            }
        };
        assert viewPager != null;
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void refreshNow() {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        startActivity(getIntent());
        overridePendingTransition(0,0);

    }

}
```

Teach me how to add navigation drawer it will helps me a lot. 
Thank you in advance for those who willing to help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980945/how-do-i-add-navigation-drawer-to-my-existing-code.This will help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add navigation drawer to my existing code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980945/how-do-i-add-navigation-drawer-to-my-existing-code)

Answer (score 0):

add the following dependencies to your apps module's build.gradle file:

```
    dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
}
```

Inside the DrawerLayout, add a layout for the main content for the UI (your primary layout when the drawer is hidden) and another view that contains the contents of the navigation drawer.

For example, the following layout uses a DrawerLayout with two child views: a FrameLayout to contain the main content (which could, for example, by populated by a Fragment at runtime), and a NavigationView for the contents of the navigation drawer.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

To configure the menu items listed in the drawer, specify a menu resource with the app:menu attribute, as shown in the example code below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
```

Create the menu resource with the corresponding file name. For example, at res/menu/drawer_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="@string/import" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="@string/slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="@string/tools" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: I have 2 tab layouts fragment.